# PHP & MySQL storing multiple values in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm basically a front end designer and new to PHP and MySQL but I want a user to be able to store multiple names and there meanings in a MySQL database table named `names` using PHP I will dynamically create form fields with JQuery every time a user clicks on a link so a user can enter 1 to 1,000,000 different names and there meanings which will be stored in a table called `names`.

All I want to know is how can I store multiple names and there meanings in a database and then display them back to the user for them to edit or delete using PHP & MySQL?

I created the MySQL table already.

```
CREATE TABLE names (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
userID INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
meaning VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<ul>
    <li><label for="name">Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></li>
    <li><label for="meaning">Meaning: </label><input type="text" name="meaning" id="meaning" /></li>
    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you have the hidden submit?  Did you mean to have a hidden userid?

Comment: The hidden field is hidden to send the info to the PHP script to do the validation.

Comment: This question is really way too general.  It sounds like you're stuck at the "PHP" part.  I suggest you run through a basic guestbook-style tutorial or three, and see what you learn.  Then come back with more specific questions.  As it stands, your question is a little to close to "give me the codez!!11!"

Comment: @RIP, no, the submit button (labeled SAVE) sends the info to the script.  I can't tell what the hidden field does based on what you have provided.

Comment: you don't have to give me the code exactly but an example of how to store multiple names and there meanings will be nice:)

Comment: @MJB I'll get rid of the hidden field then thanks.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to submit an arbitrary number of names/meanings in a single form POST, see edwin's answer.  Play around with that (do some var_dump($_POST);s) and examine the data structure that gets created via that naming scheme.  From there it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
<input name="myfield[]">
```

then you can repeat this element multiple times and in PHP you will get an array with all the values.

Instead of myfield, you can use any name. Just make sure you append the "[]" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You would somehow create an array of `name` and `meanings` out of the `POST` data, then run it through something like:

```
// Assuming count($name) == count($meaning)
for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `names` (`id`, `userID`, `name`, `meaning`) VALUES('', '', '".$name[$i]."', '".$meaning[$i]."');";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Note that since there is user input the arrays should be escaped with `addslashes` when creating them.